# Using flatDirs should be avoided because it doesn't support any meta-data formats

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

I'm seeing the following warning when building in Android Studio:

> Using flatDirs should be avoided because it doesn't support any meta-data formats

[image]

I'm integrating with an aar that is packaged locally in my `libs` directory. Is there another way to integrate without adding the following problematic block to my `build.gradle`?

```
repositories {
    flatDir {
        dirs 'libs'
    }
}
```

Comment: You could publish that AAR to Maven Local (`publishToMavenLocal`) and consume it from there. Or, publish to some other Maven repo (e.g., a private one for your team).

Comment: You may also define a local Maven or Ivy repository directly inside your project directory structure. This way you could keep the files with the project but still benefit from dependency meta-data usage. I guess Maven requires you to add (and maybe create) `.pom` files, but I think Ivy could extract the metadata directly from the file name.

Comment: @LukasKörfer can you explain a bit more what you mean by "You may also define a local Maven or Ivy repository directly inside your project directory structure"? Is there any guide you can link to for this? I don't understand what you would put for the "url" of the Maven/Ivy repository in your build.gradle in this case. Presumably you would need to put a "file://" type URL and this would depend on exactly where on the filesystem the project was located, which may differ between developers, not to mention OS

Answer (score 42):

Inside your `build.gradle` file,
add following piece of code in android block:

```
android { ..
  sourceSets {
        main {
            jniLibs.srcDirs = ['libs']
        }
    }
}
```

and add dependency as:

```
implementation (files("libs/test_name.aar"))
```

delete following block:

```
repositories {
    flatDir {
        dirs 'libs'
    }
}
```

Comment: In which file? Please give more detail

Comment: in build.gradle of app module

Answer (score 10):

Use the **LIBS** directory. Remove that code and replace it by the following in the **module.gradle**.

```
android {
    sourceSets {
        main {
            jniLibs.srcDirs = ['libs']
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

You can add the aar like this, without the need to use `flatDir` :

```
dependencies {
    implementation files('/path/to/dir/something_local.aar')
}
```

Comment: This is not working for me. Maybe it expects the `aar` to be in the projects `lib` dir, or it doesn't work on Windows.

Comment: I am on Windows and it's working. The path is relative to the gradle submodule, not the root project folder. It's not expecting anything related to `lib`. It's just a path.

Comment: simple and working

Answer (score 4):

- Step 1. On app/build.gradle file

```
    apply plugin: ....
    
    android {
     sourceSets {
            main {
                jniLibs.srcDirs = ['libs']
            }
        }
    }
```

- Step 2. At project level/build.gradle file, delete the following block:

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        flatDir {
            dirs 'libs'
        }
      }
    }
```